# Is there anything like a "if (href = ...)" command?

Tags: javascript, dom, href

In my code I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if (href = "http://hello.com")
{
whatever[0].click();
}
```

So the point is, I'm trying to get the script to click on a button only when the window is opened in a specific href.

Comment: The [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) object might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.location` contains a number of interesting values:

```
hash ""
host "stackoverflow.com"
hostname "stackoverflow.com"
href "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942858/is-there-anything-like-a-if-href-command"
pathname "/questions/21942858/is-there-anything-like-a-if-href-command"
port ""
protocol "http:"
search ""
```

so, in your example, that would be:

```
if (window.location.hostname === "hello.com") {
}
```

Or, what you probably want to do since you know the domain, is use the `pathname`:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/questions/21942858/is-there-anything-like-a-if-href-command') {
}
```

`window.location.toString()` returns the full URL (ie. what you see in your address bar):

```
>>> window.location.toString()
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942858/is-there-anything-like-a-if-href-command/21942892?noredirect=1#comment33241527_21942892"

>>> window.location === 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942858/is-there-anything-like-a-if-href-command/21942892?noredirect=1#comment33241527_21942892'
true
```

I've always avoided this, since 1) It breaks when you change protocols (http/https) 2) Breaks when you run your script on another domain. I would recommend using the `pathname`.

Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.location).

**Bonus tip**

Your example does this:

```
if (href = "http://hello.com")
```

You use *ONE* `=`, which is assignment, not comparison. You need to use `==` or `===` (this is a very common mistake, so be on the lookout for it!)

Comment: One technique to avoid the problem discussed in the tip is to use 'Yoda Coding' and write `if("http://hello.com" === href)` which would error if you forget the `=`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I knew about yoda conditioning. however I never thought about that point for using it... thanks for that tip.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah, [Yoda conditions](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html) ... I dislike 'em, and I've been programming for so long I almost never make this mistake any more. IMHO the sacrifice in readability and sanity is too much. YMMV.